# Python Loop Count Stops at 67381

Tags: python, pdf

I'm assuming this has to be a memory issue but I'm not sure. The program loops through PDF's to look for corrupted files. When a file is corrupted, it writes that location to a txt file for me to review later. When running it the first time, I logged both pass and fail scenarios to the log. After 67381 log entries, it stopped. Then I changed this logic so it only logs errors, however, in the console I did display a count of the loop so I can tell how far along the process is. There are about 190k files to loop through and at exactly 67381 the count stops every time. It looks like the python program is still running in the background as the memory and cpu keeps fluctuating but it's hard to be sure. I also don't know now if it will still write errors to the log.

Here is the code,

```
import PyPDF2, os
from time import gmtime,strftime

path = raw_input("Enter folder path of PDF files:")
t = open(r'c:\pdf_check\log.txt','w')
count = 1
for dirpath,dnames,fnames in os.walk(path):
    for file in fnames:
        print count
        count = count + 1
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
            file = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
            try:
                PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(file, "rb"))
            except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError:
                curdate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
                t.write (str(curdate) + " " + "-" + " " + file + " " + "-" + " " + "fail" + "\n")
            else:
                pass
                #curdate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
                #t.write(str(curdate) + " " + "-" + " " + file + " " + "-" + " " + "pass" + "\n")

t.close()
```

Edit 1: (New Code)
New code and the same issue:

```
import PyPDF2, os
from time import gmtime,strftime

path = raw_input("Enter folder path of PDF files:")
t = open(r'c:\pdf_check\log.txt','w')
count = 1
for dirpath,dnames,fnames in os.walk(path):
    for file in fnames:
        print count
        count = count + 1
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
            file = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
            try:
                with open(file,'rb') as f:
                    PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
            except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError:
                curdate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
                t.write (str(curdate) + " " + "-" + " " + file + " " + "-" + " " + "fail" + "\n")
                f.close()
            else:
                pass
                f.close()
                #curdate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
                #t.write(str(curdate) + " " + "-" + " " + file + " " + "-" + " " + "pass" + "\n")

t.close()
```

Edit 2: I am trying to now run this from a different machine with beefier hardware and a different version of windows (10 pro instead of server 2008 r2) but I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: `PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(file, "rb"))` isn't guaranteed to close the file. Use a context manager to make file the handle is closed (cannot hurt)

Comment: how does it stop? silently?

Comment: Yes, it just freezes, the python program is running in task manager still and cpu and memory is changing but nothing happens after waiting for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit one of the .pdf files to make it larger. That way, if the loop number your program "stops" at is smaller, you can identify the problem as a memory issue.

Else, it might be an **unusually** large pdf file that is taking your program a while to verify integrity.

Debugging this, you could print the file location of the .pdf files you open to find this particular .pdf and manually open it to investigate further..

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The issue is actually due to a random and very large corrupted PDF. So this is not a loop issue, it's a corrupted file issue.